# Website Clicks in Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

Facebook Ad Report tool allows to select from wide selection of columns for displaying. One of them is `Website Clicks`, which is defined like this:

`The number of clicks on links appearing on your ad or Page that direct people to your sites off Facebook as a result of your ad.`

How to obtain this column from Facebook API? The official documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/adreportstats/v2.2 doesn't mention this type of column. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2):

You'll find them under the action response field if you use the field 'actions_group_by' set to 'action_type'. They will appear as 'link_click'.

Comment: I added `&actions_group_by=action_type` to the request URI and `actions` to the `data_columns`. Is `website_clicks` just a sum of `link_click` keys for `actions` property in the response? For now I don't see any `link_click` keys, because none of the actions in my response have it.

Comment: Yes, website clicks is `link_click`. Do you see website clicks in the Ad Report tool and not in the API?

Comment: Yes, Ad Report tool has many different columns available, most of them are not supported by API directly. They are aggregated values perhaps that must be obtained by workarounds in the API.